# Windows store app 8.1 orientation change

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How do I apply 2 layouts when orientation changes? I have 2 layouts a below it has columns given width using `*` values. I don't know how to change those values.

I would like to do this using blend with behaviours.

Please let me know any good articles that I should refer.

*This is my landscape view*
[image: This is my landscape view]

*This is the portrait view I want*
[image: This is the portrait view I want]

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correct you want two columns:

1. The first uses the complete available space without a fixed pixel width
2. The second column should always be for example 300px width (the width that column 1 does not use)

In this case you can declare your second column width without the `*`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- implicitly 1* -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="lightblue"/>
    <Border Background="LimeGreen" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Your are able to name these `ColumnDefinitons` with the `x:Name` attribute and access them in code behind to change there widths at runtime. You can also create a data binding to do it without a code behind.